# How to store the next thing to do in GIT

Tags: git

The question is when I finish work for the day and I commit the day's work to the dev branch, is there a way I can store what needs to be done next or 1st thing tomorrow, natively in git? The closest I can think is open a branch with the task name and checkout, however cannot add more details. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe git stash is what you are looking for: https://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simply creating a text file named something like `tasks.txt` and then updating it at the end of each day?

Comment: Thanks, but I don' want to use a separate file to do that. I was thinking more like commit comments etc.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @M. Suuland, if you already began developping the next task you can stash it. Elsewhere if you haven't already began, you should consider another tool. GIT is an SCM (Source Code Management) tool and it's not meant to be used for tasks management. There is more relevant tools to do this.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have any work started to stash. I agree GIT is an SCM, but at the same time my project is not that big to use another tool for tasks. Besides I wanted to know if there is a way to do it in GIT natively.

Comment: Well, in this case use something like Hott Notes to create post-its on your computer's desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Git stash would be an option, see the following link: https://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Git-Tools-Stashing

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have any work started to stash. I could add those in the  previous commit description.

Comment: @AnwarHusain Then start some work: Create a file called "tasks.txt", put the description of what to do next in that file, add it to the index, then stash it. The next morning, unstash, look at the file to remember what to do, and then delete it from the index.

Comment: @AnwarHusain When work is done, "normal" commits can be used and their comments to describe what still needs to be done. However when work is not yet finished or non working code then stash is the way to go